# Send a file from Client to Server - not saved in server

Tags: java, sockets

This is my client code to upload a file to the server

```
try {
    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();     

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
        }
catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {

                //fileInputStream.close();
            }
```

Server code

```
   File file=null;

    InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();

    file = new File("C://some/somefile.txt" );
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];

    int bytesReceived = 0;

    while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0) {
        out.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
        System.out.println(bytesReceived);
        break;
    }
```

The file that i am uploading is not getting saved on the server. How can i correct my code? Please help?

Comment: are you closing the file correctly?

Comment: When i close i get an error, so i left it open

Comment: Remove the break statment in server code. Also close the streams.

Comment: I did, but it doesn'nt get saved. and i don't get an error when i close the files.

Comment: k remove the break statement and put close(). if you get any error post it here

Comment: i did, but i don't get any errors.

Comment: 1. Check if you can write to a file on the Server for example by just writing "This is a test." to it. If this succeeds 2. Test if you can send data from client to server correctly by sending a simple thing like a String and printing it to log or console. If both succeed, then I guess it is your reading from file that fails.

Comment: There was a mistake from my side. i corrected it. now the file is getting uploaded, but its's 0bytes. meaning nothing has got uploaded.

Comment: @Fildor hello, i am still stuck with this :(

Comment: @Illep can you please in your question edit the codesnippets to the version you are trying right now? There is still the `break` in the while loop for example. In the second snippet: Can you please instead of sk.read just write "This is a test".getBytes() to the file? And tell us what happened.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the file correctly, you need to put:

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

after you finish writing

Comment: I did, but there's no change. it doesn't get uploaded

Comment: remove the "break" in the while loop, with your code it is receiving only the first part of the file, probably you get an error when closing the outputstream because inputstream has not finished receiving

Comment: i did, but still it hasn't got uploaded.  i don't get any errors too

Comment: I added a try catch for the client and finally block. i thought it would be helpful.